# removeChild in javascript/ DOM is not working correctly when more than one is present in the function

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, removechild

**UPDATE:**
Here's the JsFiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/zAVFv/

### It seems to be not working in JsFiddle, but guess it serves to show the whole code - html, css and Js.

I am facing a very weird situation in DOM editing using Javascript. My sample code is below. Basically, the swapCells would take in two objects, which have 2 children each - one is an img element, and the other is a textNode. What I want to see is the how removeChild works.

I have marked the 2 lines where all the confusion comes from.
issue#1 is on the line where sourceTD has its child removed, issue#2 is when the lastChild is removed from the destinationTD.

Let me explain how the code below is running:
a) when only issue line#1 is present in the code, the sourceTD child gets removed, the output says source has 1 child of img type; destination has 2 children - img and text ---- works as expected
b) when only issue line #2 is present in the code, the destinationTD child gets removed, again works similar to above, AS EXPECTED
c) NOW THE PROBLEM - when both lines are present in the code, it only removes the sourceTD lastChild. output is received only for the sourceTD part of alerts. **The destinationTD alerts are not coming, so I am unable to evaluate whether the destination child got removed**

CODE:

```
function swapCells(sourceTD, destinationTD){

//line below is issue line#1 
sourceTD.removeChild(sourceTD.lastChild);  

//line below is issue line#2
destinationTD.removeChild(destinationTD.lastChild);

    if(sourceTD.hasChildNodes()){
        alert("Source has: " + sourceTD.childNodes.length);
        alert(sourceTD.childNodes[0].alt); 
        alert(sourceTD.childNodes[1].nodeName); 
    }
destinationTD.removeChild(destinationTD.lastChild);
    if(destinationTD.hasChildNodes()){
        alert("Destination has: " + destinationTD.childNodes.length);
        alert(destinationTD.childNodes[0].alt); 
        alert(destinationTD.childNodes[1].nodeName); 
    }
}
```

Please let me know why the code is behaving abnormally when both the issue lines are present. Also, is there something like a function can remove only a single node, or that only a single removeChild will work...????? I am confused.

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps use http://jsfiddle.net/ and include your HTML as well ... that will help

Comment: @ManseUK
I have added the jsfiddle link to question (http://jsfiddle.net/zAVFv/)

Comment: @RobG
http://jsfiddle.net/zAVFv/

Comment: updated your jsfiddle ----> http://jsfiddle.net/zAVFv/1/

Answer (score 1):

Sorted -> http://jsfiddle.net/zAVFv/3/

The first childNode of TD is a newline not the img element .... incremented the numbers by 1 and its working fine ... seems a little flimsy to use in a prod environment - unless you can control the HTML - perhaps look at using `getelementbytagname('img')` instead ?

Comment: == umm.. i m sorry, but it doesnt seem to work as i expected. Could you please look into http://jsfiddle.net/zAVFv/4/

both sourcTD and DestinationTD removeChild are mentioned, but i see that the code runs only for the sourceTD set of alerts. what gives?

Comment: @arunnair thats because its been removed !

Answer (score 0):

When you have both lines in there, you end up calling `destinationTD.removeChild(destinationTD.lastChild);` twice, so both children get removed. Your if statement then evaluates to false because `destinationTD` has no child nodes, so you don't get anything output - in this case, lack of output is proof that the code IS working, rather than proof that it ISN'T.

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh... figured it out.

the issue was because of an error created due to referencing a childnode that was no more present, after deletion.

For example, if the sourceTD has 3 children, and were referenced as childNodes[1], and childNodes[2], then upon deletion of the lastChild of the sourceTD, there is no longer childNodes[2], as there are only 2 left and no third node anymore. As a result of this error in JS, the remaining code is somehow suppressed and not run. so this is the reason why the destinationTD alerts also are getting suppressed.

Stupid referencing..!

Thanks everyone, especially @ManseUK for all the help